# Try all possible parenthesis placement on a math calculation

Tags: python, combinations, parentheses, calculation

so I have a list with number and math operators.

```
number = ['10', '6', '2', '6', '3', '1'] 
operators = ['+', '*', '//, -,'+']
```

Then I build my statement like that

```
calculation = num[0] + operator[0] + num [1] ...
```

Now I took a function I found here to generate all valid parenthesis.

```
def parens(left, right, string):
    if left == 0 and right == 0:
        arr.append(string)

    if left > 0:
        parens(left - 1, right + 1, string + "(")

    if right > 0:
        parens(left, right - 1, string + ")")
```

## That now spits out an list called parentheses, that contains all combinations

One possible combination is now `[(((((())))))]` now I put it in the Equation like that.

```
 for index_paranthesis in range(0, 12, 2):    # Steps of two, to get all uneven parenthesis
    calculation += parenthesis[index_paranthesis] 

    calculation += number[i_number]
    i_number += 1

    calculation += parenthesis[index_paranthesis + 1] #to get the even indexed parenthesis

    calculation += operators[i_operator]
    i_operator += 1
```

So after that i get the first, combination of parenthesis like

```
calculation = (10(+(6(*(2(//)6)-)3)+)1)
```

So the problem now is that with eval(calculation). It says that that is a syntax error. I know thats the problem but my question is how to I get all functional parenthesis combination and apply them.
Thanks for your time all ready and I hope you can help me.

Comment: What is `2(//)6` supposed to mean? You shouldn't have parentheses around just the operator.

Comment: You're missing some quotes in the `operators` list.

Comment: Should `num[0]` and `operator[0]` be `number[0]` and `operators[0]`?

Comment: What are `parenthesis` and `i_number`?

Comment: @Barmar, yeah I know, but I dont want to set the parentheses myself I look for an algorithm that can do that. The function I stated does generate every possible combination and all valid combination are in that too. I want to know how to filter out the unvalid ones.

Comment: Related: http://beutil.blogspot.com/2012/12/exercicis-de-primaria-amb-python-iv.html?m=1

Comment: @Barmar i_number would be just the index for number = [] and be set to 0 and than goes to 5 just to get the 6 numbers out of the list

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but if what you say is true and this generates all combinations (including bad ones), then you can loop through the combinations and wrap the offending line (the one that causes the error) with a try/except block.

Comment: Although, I would think a little harder and try to not generate any invalid expressions in the first place. For large inputs, you will generate many invalid expressions and waste a lot of time trying to eval them

Comment: @SyntaxVoid yeah that was my Question how do I generate any not invalid expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the 'easier to ask for forgiveness than permission' approach and enclose your eval in a try/except.

```
try:
    eval(expression)
except SyntaxError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it